# How to always observe the text of label and change color in swift 4?

Tags: swift, uilabel

I have labels that are always changing for a bitcoin app and I am trying to attach a custom UILabel class to my labels to show the + and - price change in the past day. If there is a + increase I want to change the label to green color and red for -. How can i do this?

Edit:

I need to attach a custom UIlabel class to the Labels on the storyboard that always reads the string value converted to an int and if the value is < 0, change color to red, if value is > 0 change color to green

Comment: You're updating the label. Why can't you also update the color? Update your question with relevant code. Show what you are having trouble with.

Comment: Because I am updating the label from more than one place, I dont want to repeat the same code over again. There must be a way to do it by attaching a custom UILabel class to the label I just dont know the function to constantly observe a label

Comment: As I said, update your question to clarify what issue you are trying to solve, including relevant code.

Comment: You could subclass `UILabel` and override the `setText:` (or `setAttributedText:`) and check the current value and change the color accordingly. If you add also a currency, what about adding also a value "price" to have a easier guess of "+/-" comparing the current value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try

```
var ob:NSKeyValueObservation?
```

//

```
ob = lbl.observe(\.text) { (lbl,ob) in

    // check text here and change color
}
```

**OR**

```
class Cus:UILabel {

 override var text:String? {
    didSet{
       // ! won't crash as long as you guarantee int value is set
        self.textColor = Int(text!)! < 0 ? UIColor.red : UIColor.green

    }
 }
}
```